# Disable JW Player control bar during a certain time of the video

Tags: jwplayer

Just like the title says, how could I create an event that disables the control bar during a certain time of the video? I am using JW Player 5.10.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Once a player is set up on a page, it isn't possible to remove elements after it is already instantiated, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to force this, you could brute force it by creating two jwplayers that both use the same video/playlist.

Have one with the controls hidden and one with the controls displayed.

Here is the tricky part, set up a "timeout" that last the amount of time that it would take to get to the part of the video you want the controls hidden.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){"Hide the jwplayer with controls, unhide the other jwplayer"}, 30000);
```

The 30000 represents the amount of time in milliseconds.

From there you have an event which would allow you to hide the jwplayer with controls (set the div element to hidden). Finally, set the other jwplayer div to not be hidden.